# Problem in set view in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

[image]I have a tab based application with 4 views associated with 4 tabs. I want all 3 views in portrait form and only one landscape form.

I have done these settings for that particular view:

Set the required value in Supported interface orientations of info.plist.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
}
```

In IB set the orientation attribute as landscape.

In `-(void)viewDidLoad` I have set `self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);`

After done all above setting, its still not coming in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, and please correct me if I do not, then you want to have 3 views in portrait **all of the time** and one view in landscape **all of the time**. To accomplish this, set the orientation of the status bar for each viewController in `viewWillAppear`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: @Archana Chaurasia: see above

Comment: I have implemented it, but doing like this, the device is changing to landscape mode but the view content is still in portrait, only changed its x,y coordinate according to device. Is it possible to paste screen shot here. If yes, how?

Comment: @Archana First, you should remove the manual `self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);` and return `NO` for `shouldAutorotate`.

Yes, you can upload a screenshot. Edit your post and along the top of the window where you type, hover the mouse over the little icons. One reads "add images" or "add media" or some such thing.

Comment: I have remove all above things but still it is coming like this(see screen shot). I want tab bar at bottom and view in landscape mode, but its moving with device.